# compare 2 sheets in excel and show different result and summary

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have one doubet in excel how to compare two sheets in excel and show summarized result and if any values get differnce then show sheet name

```
sheet1: eid | name |sal 
        1   |  ab  |100
        2   |de    |300

Sheet2: eid|name |sal
        1  |ab |100
        2 |ra   |300
        3 |df   |400
```

based on above 2 sheets
need summarized report : sheet1 count 2
sheet2 count 3
de   exist in sheet1 and not exist in sheet2
id 3 row exist in sheet2 and not exist in sheet1

could you please tell me how to write vba script to achieve this task in excel .

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic1 As Object, objDic2 As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, aKey
    Dim arrData
    Dim iR As Long: iR = 0
    Set objDic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load data from Sheet1
    Set rngData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 2) & "|" & arrData(i, 3)
        objDic1(sKey) = ""
    Next i
    ' Load data from Sheet2
    Set rngData = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 2) & "|" & arrData(i, 3)
        objDic2(sKey) = ""
    Next i
    ReDim arrRes(objDic1.Count + objDic2.Count + 3, UBound(arrData, 2))
    arrRes(0, 0) = "eid"
    arrRes(0, 1) = "name"
    arrRes(0, 2) = "sal"
    arrRes(0, 3) = "Note"
    ' Comparing data
    For Each sKey In objDic1.keys
        If Not objDic2.exists(sKey) Then
            aKey = Split(sKey, "|")
            iR = iR + 1
            For i = 0 To UBound(aKey)
                arrRes(iR, i) = aKey(i)
            Next
            arrRes(iR, 3) = "Not in Sheet2"
        End If
    Next
    For Each sKey In objDic2.keys
        If Not objDic1.exists(sKey) Then
            aKey = Split(sKey, "|")
            iR = iR + 1
            For i = 0 To UBound(aKey)
                arrRes(iR, i) = aKey(i)
            Next
            arrRes(iR, 3) = "Not in Sheet1"
        End If
    Next
    ' Row count for each sheet
    arrRes(iR + 2, 0) = "SheetName"
    arrRes(iR + 2, 1) = "RowCount"
    arrRes(iR + 3, 0) = "Sheet1"
    arrRes(iR + 3, 1) = objDic1.Count
    arrRes(iR + 4, 0) = "Sheet2"
    arrRes(iR + 4, 1) = objDic2.Count
    ' Write output to sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(iR + 5, 4).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The script to generate a new summary sheet for comparing `Sheet1` & `Sheet2`.

```vb
Sub CompareSheets()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim summaryWs As Worksheet
    Dim row1 As Long, row2 As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim diffCount As Long
    
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set summaryWs = Worksheets("Summary")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If summaryWs Is Nothing Then
        Set summaryWs = Worksheets.Add
        summaryWs.Name = "Summary"
    Else
        '// Clear existing content if sheet already exists
        summaryWs.Cells.Clear
    End If
    
    summaryWs.Range("A1").Value = "Summary"
    summaryWs.Range("A2").Value = "---"
    summaryWs.Range("A4").Value = "Sheet1 id Count"
    summaryWs.Range("B4").Value = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    summaryWs.Range("A5").Value = "Sheet2 id Count"
    summaryWs.Range("B5").Value = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    summaryWs.Range("A7").Value = "Differences"
    
    diffCount = 0
    For row1 = 2 To ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws2.Range("A:A"), ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value) = 0 Then
            diffCount = diffCount + 1
            summaryWs.Range("A" & diffCount + 7).Value = "ID " & ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value & " exists in Sheet1 and not in Sheet2"
        Else
            For col = 2 To ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                If ws1.Cells(row1, col).Value <> ws2.Cells(Application.Match(ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value, ws2.Range("A:A"), 0), col).Value Then
                    diffCount = diffCount + 1
                    summaryWs.Range("A" & diffCount + 7).Value = "ID " & ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value & ", Column " & ws1.Cells(1, col).Value & " has different values"
                End If
            Next col
        End If
    Next row1
    
    For row2 = 2 To ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws1.Range("A:A"), ws2.Cells(row2, 1).Value) = 0 Then
            diffCount = diffCount + 1
            summaryWs.Range("A" & diffCount + 7).Value = "ID " & ws2.Cells(row2, 1).Value & " exists in Sheet2 and not in Sheet1"
        End If
    Next row2
    
    summaryWs.Columns.AutoFit
    
    MsgBox "Done!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Output example,
[image]

Comment: Could you please help me in Difference can We get actual  values in differences output Example  ID=1 column name has diffferenc values sheet1  is abc and sheet 2 is ab values. could you please help on it

Answer (score 0):

just change `Sheet1` and `Sheet1` to your actual worksheet objects variable names

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim dict1 As Object
        Set dict1 = GetDict(Sheet1)
        
    Dim dict2 As Object
        Set dict2 = GetDict(Sheet2)
        
        Dim diffDict As Object
            If GetDiffs(dict1, dict2, _
                        diffDict) Then
                MsgBox "ids in Sheet1 not in Sheet2:" & vbLf & vbTab & Join(diffDict.Keys, vbLf & vbTab)
            End If
            If GetDiffs(dict2, dict1, _
                        diffDict) Then
                MsgBox "ids in Sheet2 not in Sheet1:" & vbLf & vbTab & Join(diffDict.Keys, vbLf & vbTab)
            End If
                
End Sub

Function GetDict(sh As Worksheet) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        Dim ids As Variant
            ids = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Value
           
            Dim i As Long
                For i = LBound(ids) To UBound(ids)
                    dict(ids(i, 1)) = i
                Next
                
                    Set GetDict = dict
End Function
Function GetDiffs(dict1 As Object, dict2 As Object, _
                  diffDict As Object) As Boolean
    Set diffDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim key As Variant
        For Each key In dict1
            If Not dict2.Exists(key) Then
                diffDict(key) = dict1(key)
            End If
        Next
        GetDiffs = diffDict.Count > 0
End Function
```